# Modify the max zoom level of a Google Map Type

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to set the `maxZoom` level of the `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` to 21. Actually, he's set to 14 (inspected with the firebug console).

Set the property of the `google.maps` object 'maxZoom' doesn't work in this case, and I already try to modify the `google.maps.mapTypes` object, but without success.

```
var options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_centre,lng_centre),   
    zoom: 14, 
    maxZoom: 21,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,   
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    styles: [ 
        {featureType: "poi", stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]} 
        ]                   
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"),options);
```

AND

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(event){

    var mapTypeRegistry = map.mapTypes;

    var currentMapTypeId = map.getMapTypeId();

    var mapType = mapTypeRegistry.get(currentMapTypeId);

    mapType.maxZoom = 21;
  });
```

So, is there a way to increase the zoom level of the mapType HYBRID ?

Thanks.

Comment: could you show us the code when you're trying to set the Max zoom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you changed `mapType` object's property ( `maxZoom`, `minZoom`, etc... ), the changed effect will take a place *ONLY AFTER* the map's type will be changed to that `mapType`. For example , if current `mapType` is `TERRAIN`, and you changed `TERRAIN`'s `maxZoom`, `maxZoom` will work only after changing `mapType` to another type (e.g. `ROADMAP`,`HYBRID`,etc..) and back to `TERRAIN`.

Instead of setting `mapType`'s `maxZoom` option,use core map's `maxZoom` option. Add listener for `"maptypeid_changed"` event, and when event occurs, change `maxZoom` option of `map`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function(event){
    if( map.getMapTypeId() === google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN ){
        map.setOptions({maxZoom:/*For example*/5});
    }else 
    if( map.getMapTypeId() === google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP ){
        map.setOptions({maxZoom:/*For example*/8});
    }//Etc...
    else{
        map.setOptions({maxZoom:/*For example*/21});
    }
});
```

Comment: I've combined your solution and my 'tilesloaded' event. It works ! Thanks !

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV Of course it should work with `'tilesloaded'` event, but it is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Note that if your problem is a common one, simply that your markers are so close together that the initial zoom is so large that all you see is the pin and "fill color" around it, this solution will prevent the user (of f.ex. a mobile phone to reach the place) from zooming in far enough to make the exact location. It is a correct answer to the question as written, though.