# maxZoom in Google Maps 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to change the maxZoom of a map to level 24? I will be adding an overlay of highly-detailed imagery and would like to provide the user with the ability to zoom in more.

I have found some code ([Modify the max zoom level of a Google Map Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517848/modify-the-max-zoom-level-of-a-google-map-type/10519085#10519085)) that is getting me closer, but no cigar just yet! See http://jsfiddle.net/vankerck/3qAkB/17/ for a more complete sample. Note that if you toggle between satellite and roads a couple of times, you will eventually be able to zoom down to level 24 when looking at roads.

```
function initialize() {
    var maxZoom = 24;
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(26.966, -80.612);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: maxZoom,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        maxZoom: maxZoom
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function (event) {
        $('#level').html('Level: ' + map.getZoom());
        var mapTypeRegistry = map.mapTypes;
        var currentMapTypeId = map.getMapTypeId();
        var mapType = mapTypeRegistry.get(currentMapTypeId);
        mapType.maxZoom = maxZoom;
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function (event) {
        map.setOptions({ maxZoom: maxZoom });
    });
}
```

Thank you,

Marianne

Comment: It will not have any effect when you increase the maxZoom of a base-mapType, the modified maxZoom will be ignored when it exceeds the built-in value.